# Laravel PHP Sessions for IPS Community

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, invision-power-board

I'm trying to install IPS Community(https://invisioncommunity.com/) on a fresh local laravel server. However, when I enter the installation process I get the following error. It might be worth mentioning the server is running on a homestead server too.

[The installer uses PHP sessions to store data, however PHP sessions are currently not working correctly on your server. This is an issue you will need to contact your host about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evloC.png)

Does anyone know how to enable PHP sessions?

Comment: Tried checking phpinfo(); ?

Comment: I did, and everything looked fine... Strangely enough deleting the entire folder and putting it back seemed to fix the problem...

Comment: Then it might be file permission issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone having this issue... You need to delete the "Constants.php" in your IPS directory to fix this.